# How to connect Windows PC to a Synology NAS via a 2-router configuration?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, nas, synology

I'm using Synology DS918+ NAS. It is connected via 2 routers. The best way to explain it is to show it in a diagram (sorry for my mad MS Paint skills):

[image]

So what I am trying to do is to connect from the PC (running Windows 7 Pro) to the NAS for the purpose of setting up a backup.

What is the way to do that? (It's somewhat above my networking/router config skills.)

PS. Note that I **cannot change** the configuration of routers. And I understand that things would be easier if I plugged in my NAS into the "main router" on that diagram.

PS2. I tried connecting from that PC to the NAS via the `user-name.synology.me` website, but it kept giving me "Site unavailable" error. I believe that it has something to do with the fact that we have a static IP (on the public internet) on that "main router". (Although `user-name.synology.me` access to the NAS works if I try to connect to it from my iPad that is on a cellular network, i.e. different public IP.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Wireless Router has Internet, and then move the PC from the main router (modem) to the Wireless Router. Use an Ethernet connection here. Now all your stuff (if the above picture is complete) will be on one subnet and you can connect the PC to your NAS

Note about the original post - you said you could not change the configuration of the routers so I took this into account when devising a simple answer for this issue

Comment: Did you try as per above?

Comment: _PS. Note that I cannot change the configuration of routers. And I understand that things would be easier if I plugged in my NAS into the "main router" on that diagram._

Comment: You do not need to change the configuration to move the PC to the wireless router. Just plug it in to a spare Ethernet port (most have 4 Ethernet ports). It will pick up DHCP from the Wireless router.  You can try plugging the NAS into the main router but then everything on Wireless will be on  a different subnet

Comment: Just to be clear, moving the NAS to the main router works, but I am quite sure your wireless is on a different subnet, so wireless devices will not talk to the NAS. Move everything to wireless to solve this